# Tesseract Recognition of dates

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

[Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8epLM.jpg)

Hello, I'm trying to use Tesseract to recognize dates from receipts. This code works well to extract the total on the receipt but doesn't seem to work for the dates as it prints out empty. 
What am I missing here to get it to work?

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
img = Image.open('Rec.jpg')
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='-psm 6'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to use `tesseract` command line with `psm` setting to `12` and got the correct date `08/21/2017`.

[image]

`--psm 12` means to set `segmentation mode` for `Sparse text with OSD`.

You can use command `tesseract --help` to find out the `--psm` supported by `tesseract v4.00.00alpha` which is used in test.

Hope this could help.